# rxjs map outputting incorrect typing

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
combineLatest([of(1), of('test')]).pipe(
  map(([myNumber, myString]) => {
    return [myNumber, myString];
  }),
  map(([myNewNumber, myNewString]) => {
    const test = myNewString.length;
  })
);
```

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number'.   Property
>   'length' does not exist on type 'number'.

How can I write this so the typing is correct without casing the return `as [number, string]` ?

Comment: You can use `map(([myNewNumber, myNewString]: [number, string]) ...)` because I guess TypeScript can't know you're expecting just two items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ts converts `[string, number]` into `(string | number)[]` unless you explicitly specify type of each item:

```js
combineLatest([of(1), of('test')]).pipe(
    map(([myNumber, myString]) => {
        return [myNumber, myString] as [number, string];
    }),
    map(([myNewNumber, myNewString]) => {
        const test = myNewString.length;
    }),
);
```

Or you can use Object instead of Array if you don't want to deal with explicit types:

```js
combineLatest([of(1), of('test')]).pipe(
    map(([myNumber, myString]) => {
        return {myNumber, myString};
    }),
    map(({myNewNumber, myNewString}) => {
        const test = myNewString.length;
    })
);
```

Comment: If you are using TS3.6, you can also write `return [myNumber, myString] as const;` in the first example.